# Could not find method android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance

Tags: android, facebook

I know there's lot's of these questions, and "solution" is make sure that Android Private Libraries are checked. In my case they **are**, any other hints? App crash at very beginning.

Here goes stack trace

> 08-02 00:22:58.316: E/Trace(4825): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.035: W/dalvikvm(4825): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.035: W/dalvikvm(4825): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.045: I/dalvikvm(4825): Could not find method android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance, referenced from method com.facebook.Session.postActiveSessionAction
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.045: W/dalvikvm(4825): VFY: unable to resolve static method 187: Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;.getInstance (Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.045: D/dalvikvm(4825): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0009
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.075: D/AndroidRuntime(4825): Shutting down VM
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.075: W/dalvikvm(4825): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4825): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4825): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at com.facebook.Session.postActiveSessionAction(Session.java:1215)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at com.facebook.Session.setActiveSession(Session.java:765)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at com.facebook.Session.openActiveSession(Session.java:865)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at com.facebook.Session.openActiveSession(Session.java:805)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at com.example.firstandroidapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>
> 08-02 00:22:59.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved. From some odd reason ADT preconfigured by google attached same file in /libs directory of project. When you add facebook SDK to class path it attaches it as well. Problem is they have diffrent versions (and sha-1 hash) so eclipse had problem what to do. I just remove /libs directory and it worked. Runs app from facebook tutorial successfully.

Comment: Thank you for the post! Had the exact same error and you saved lives!

Comment: @user1638809 No problem mate. I think someone should write to FB ask them to add some note with explaination to their tutorial. It's very frustrating when you cannot run simplest example and many people use ADT by Google.

Comment: I have same error ,but can not solve .. any other solution of this?